# Why is it necessary to assume that examples and labels are drawn from a joint distribution in empirical loss minimization?

Tags: machine-learning, joint-distribution, loss-functions, risk

Multiple sources have indicated that when trying to minimize empirical loss, $1/N \sum_i L(f(x_i, w), y_i)$, where $L$ is some loss function, $y_i$ is the true label, and $f(x_i, w)$ is the predicted label, one must assume that $x_i$ and $y_i$ are drawn from $p(x, y)$.  Why is this the case?  Isn't this a tautology, that is, isn't it always possible to construct a joint distribution over $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 0):

You don't assume that there is any joint probability distribution for your training data (that would be trivially true, as you said) but you assume that both the training data $x_i, y_i$ as well as unseen test data, that you later want to apply your algorithm on, are drawn from the same distribution $p(x,y)$. If you would drop this assumption you could still minimize the objective function $1/N \sum_i L(f(x_i, w), y_i)$ but you would have no guarantees that the estimated parameters $w$ perform any good on test data drawn from a different distribution than your training data.

If you read into computational learning theory you will find that you can (loosely) bound the test error based on some properties of your learning algorithm and the amount of training data, but these bounds only hold as long as the distribution for test and training data is the same.